# Why this code does not print what it should?

Tags: java

This code should draw table, but it doesn't. Why?
The code compiles but it doesn't print enything.
Here is code:

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Nizovi{

    public static char table[][]= new char[10][10] ;



    public static void drawTable(){
        // this should draw table   

        int k=1;
        while(k <= 30){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i < table.length; i++){

            for(int j=0; j < table[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print("|"+ table[i][j] + "|");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }

        k=1;
        while(k <= 30){
            System.out.print("-");
        }

    }


    public static void buildTable(){
        // and this is supposed to fill it with *    
        for(char[] row: table){
            Arrays.fill(row, '*');
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Nizovi.buildTable();
        Nizovi.drawTable();

    }
    }
```

I can't see what i miss. What's wrong here?

Comment: you need to update your k variable inside your loops

Answer (score 4):

Your loop says `while(k <= 30)...` - how is k ever to reach 30? Nothing is changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Increment `k` inside the while blocks:

```
 while(k <= 30){
        System.out.print("-");
        k++; // add this to your loops
 }
```

In your code, `k` is not updated within the loops, it therefore remains `1` and stays always less-or-equal to `30` (`k <= 30` always yields `true`)

know as "an endless loop"

Output with incrementing the `k` references within the `while`-blocks:

```
------------------------------
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
|*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*||*|
------------------------------
```

(Make sure you update both `while`-blocks (hence the plural))

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is different from `for` loop. `for` assumes you are going to do something a certain amount of times and can therefore automatically increment the index by executing the `i++` part. while only checks if the condition is fulfilled. Therefore you should take care of the state of the condition and increment the counter `k` in the body of the `while` loop by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

increment k in while loop

```
while(k <= 30){
    System.out.print("-");
    k++;
}
```